# Do plays of track previews count towards the track playcount on Spotify?

Tags: spotify

When users hear track previews created by the Spotify web API track preview URL, does that count towards the track's listed playcount on Spotify?

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not.

(Answers must be at least 30 chars, so obligatory filter...)